# How to go through records in order of associated date?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I have 2 tables: Appointments and Patients. A Patient can have multiple appointments. I have created a form (single form) that shows ApptDate (in Appointments) and Patient information (from Patient). I want to be able to display Patient information ordered by ApptDate. I have an unbound control on the form for the date to start with, and want a button that displays each patient with an appointment on the start date, or the next date if all of the patients on the start date have been displayed.

I have been able to use DoCmd.FindRecord to display the first patient on a given date, and a button with DoCmd.FindNext to advance through all of the patients with appointments on that date, but I can't figure out how to get to the next date in Appts.

```
Private Sub SearchStart_AfterUpdate()
' Me.SearchStart is unbound and has the date to start the search for patients
    Me.ApptDate.SetFocus    'This is the control on the form bound to ApptDate in the table of Appointments
    DoCmd.FindRecord Me.SearchStart, , , True, , , True
End Sub

Private Sub NextPatientButton_Click()
    Me.ApptDate.SetFocus
    DoCmd.FindNext
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Appointments table has field "Patient" which is the ID field in the Patient table.
Created a Form ("frmByVisitDate2") with data: SELECT Appontments.ApptDate, Appontments.Patient, Patients.WholeName FROM Patients INNER JOIN Appontments ON Patients.ID = Appontments.Patient ORDER BY Appontments.ApptDate;

Date to start searching is in control StartDate

```
Private Sub StartDate_AfterUpdate()
'   After date is selected go to first record >= StartDate.
DoCmd.SearchForRecord acDataForm, "frmByVisitDate2", acFirst, "[ApptDate] >= #" & Me.StartDate & "#"
End Sub

Private Sub NextPatientButton_Click()
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmByVisitDate2", acNext
'The following prevents error when no more records found and displays last record
If IsNull(Me.ApptDate) Then DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmByVisitDate2", acPrevious
End Sub

Private Sub PreviousPatientButton_Click()
On Error Resume Next    'Prevents error if no previous record found
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmByVisitDate2", acPrevious
End Sub
```